# Send only one click to monkeyrunner at specified position

Tags: android, scripting, android-monkey

Here is a more typical command line, which will launch your application and send 500 pseudo-random events to it:

```
$ adb shell monkey -p your.package.name -v 500
```

but I am wondering how can I send only one click to my app at position 50,50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```